# React - Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute 'attrName'

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have my own reusable Button component with the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Button extends Component {
    render() {
        const {href, border, children, className} = this.props;
        let baseClass = 'button';
        border && (baseClass += ' button-border');
        className && (baseClass += ' ' + className);
        return (
            href ? (
                    <a className={baseClass} {...this.props}><span>{children}</span></a>
                ) :
                (
                    <button {...this.props} className={baseClass}><span>{children}</span></button>
                )
        )
    }
}

Button.propTypes = {
    href: PropTypes.string,
    border: PropTypes.bool,
    className: PropTypes.string
}

Button.defaultProps = {
    border: false,
    className: ''
}

export default Button;
```

I'm then calling it in other components without the border prop, as I usually use it only for secondary type call to actions (please keep in mind the code is simplified just to illustrate the issue, so passing an additional className in order to avoid the warning is not a feasible solution).

I use the following code to call the button:

```
<Button>Continue</Button>
```

As you can see, there is no border prop specified, so the component is receiving the correct value from defaultProps: false.

Unfortunately after running my application I come across the following warning: 
*react-dom.development.js:506 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `border`.*

I have read multiple other questions with similar issue, but none of them were helpful.

In my implementation I also tried to amend the

```
border && (baseClass += ' button-border');
```

to

```
border ? (baseClass += ' button-border') : '';
```

but it didn't solve anything.

I also moved the Button.propTypes to static propTypes before the component render - without any result.

In terms of packages, I'm using:
- react 16.8.2
- prop-types 15.7.2

Thanks for any leads on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how the component itself is defined (i.e. the `defaultProps` and `propTypes` on `<Button />`), however this is due to the following code, which is passed to both `<a/>` and `<button/>`.

```
{...this.props}
```

By doing so, we're passing `border={false}` to the native anchor and button elements, which is seemingly not supported, or at the very least will provoke an error from React. If you remove those lines, you'll note the error disappears; it might be worth explicitly passing down the props you'd like to these tags.

Comment: It definitely solved the issue, thanks! Is there any other way to approach it? It bothers me a little that it is necessary to extract every single thing and then update the ui package accordingly every time I figure out I might use an extra event handler or id in the component.

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal, but it somewhat falls in line with React's idiomatic approach of being declarative, which in this case would mean identifying and passing down just the props needed by the children. Moreover, there's actually an eslint rule that forbids prop spreading (https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md). If you still do want to use prop spread, you defined something like `{...customProps}` that specifically removes attributes that seem to provoke errors.